# Wordpress: sort get_pages by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field "weight" with numeric values at Wordpress site. I want to sort pages using this values.
But I have a problem. It's a very old site, and pages is shown using get_pages(). I can change it to get_posts, but if I do it, I will have to rewrite a big amount of code...
So, maybe the easier solution exists? How can I sort my pages using custom field value without changing get_pages to get_posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort pages with custom field value.. but you have to change `get_pages to get_posts`

i think wordpress not provide method to sort pages according to custom field with `get_pages` function.

```
$listingPages = get_posts( 
array(
    'meta_key' => 'streetAdd',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort pages by using standard argument options provided by wordpress.

```
<?php ` get_pages( $args ); ` ?> 

<?php ` $args = array(
    `sort_order` => `asc`,
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'authors' => '',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'parent' => -1,
    'exclude_tree' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args); `
?>
```

**meta_key**

(string) Only include pages with this meta key.

**meta_value**

(string) Only include pages with this meta value. Requires $meta_key.

**sort_column**

(string) What columns to sort pages by, comma-separated. Accepts 'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_title', 'post_name', 'post_modified', 'menu_order', 'post_modified_gmt', 'post_parent', 'ID', 'rand', 'comment*count'. 'post*' can be omitted for any values that start with it. Default 'post_title'.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `get_posts` unfortunately there is no option for `orderby` and `order` in `get_pages`.

Check the documentation for [get_pages()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) and for [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

For get_pages the query will be like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'weight',
);
$listingPages = get_pages( $args );
```

But I personally feel that you should use `get_posts` because it has many parameters for filter. Which will be suitable for condition.